# How to make good bibliography with hyperlink?

Tags: bibliographies, hyperref

I have been struggling to have something like this:

1) In the text:

> 'It has been shown (Arnold et al., 2011) that space technology is expected to...'

2) In bibliography:

> Arnold, J. P., S. J. Peter (2011), The growth of space instrumentation. Journal of Adv. Tech., 63,5565-5578.

How can I have it as above with a hyperlink on "Arnold et al., 2011" without necessarily having it as

> [1] Arnold, J. P....

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you using BibTeX, BibLaTeX or a manual bibliography? Which style are you using so far? This should be easy with the right style and `hyperref`.

Comment: @Brett: Welcome to tex.sx! Note that it is unusual around here to sign your questions (as there is already a box with your username below it) or to have any greeting. A suggestion: Change your username to something more telling than "user3661".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I suggest to use [biblatex](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/biblatex.html). Below you'll find a compilable minimal example with hyperlinks and some basic formatting (autor-year-style, use of "et al." in citations).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=authoryear,maxcitenames=1,maxbibnames=99]{biblatex}

% Remove "In: " before journaltitle for @article
\renewbibmacro{in:}{%
  \ifentrytype{article}{%
  }{%
    \printtext{\bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}%
  }%
}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Arn11,
  author = {Arnold, J. P. and Peter, S. J.},
  year = {2011},
  title = {The growth of space instrumentation},
  journaltitle = {Journal of Adv. Tech.},
  volume = {63},
  pages = {5565--5578},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

It has been shown \autocite{Arn11} that space technology is expected to~\dots

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

(The filecontents environment is only used to include some external files directly into the example, so that it compiles. It is not necessary for the solution.)

Comment: @ Lockstep....I appreciate it.

Comment: @ Lockstep....I appreciate it. @ Martin I use TexShop/BibDesk...with natbib as ref style on Mac Leopard 10.5. I wish I can do this without necessarily going back to install Biblatex again, as this is the only bit that remains to do for my thesis.