# How to make a link to a paper in bibiography?

Tags: bibliographies, hyperlink

I have a paper in the .bib file:

```
@ARTICLE{kupka_muthsam_2017,
       author = {{Kupka}, Friedrich and {Muthsam}, Herbert J.},
        title = "{Modelling of stellar convection}",
      journal = {Living Reviews in Computational Astrophysics},
     keywords = {Convection, Stars, Modelling, Hydrodynamics, Numerics},
         year = 2017,
        month = jul,
       volume = {3},
       number = {1},
          eid = {1},
        pages = {1},
          doi = {10.1007/s41115-017-0001-9},
       adsurl = {https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2017LRCA....3....1K},
      adsnote = {Provided by the SAO/NASA Astrophysics Data System}
}
```

In the reference section, the paper is currently shown like this:

[image]

I want to make the text "Living Reviews in Computational Astrophysics, 3(1):1" a blue link and point it to a URL (https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2017LRCA....3....1K), so readers can quickly click on it and see the paper, instead of searching for it. How can I do this?

I've seen this done in other papers, like this:

[image]

Other papers that use such links in bibliography:

- https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/link_gateway/2018A%26A...616A...9L/PUB_PDF
- https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/link_gateway/2017PhRvF...2h3501A/EPRINT_PDF
- https://arxiv.org/pdf/1804.07760v2
- https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/link_gateway/2018AJ....156...58B/PUB_PDF

Comment: Which bibliographic style are you using? You might want to try "plainurl": http://tug.ctan.org/biblio/bibtex/contrib/urlbst/plainurl.bst

Comment: Have you given the previous answers a try? This is a somewhat common question:

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/100782/add-a-hyperlink-in-bibtex
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35977/how-to-add-a-url-to-a-latex-bibtex-file
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/285710/hyperref-link-to-bibliography-entry
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11293/how-to-make-good-bibliography-with-hyperlink
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/314390/hyperlinked-bibliography

Comment: @pluton I'm using apalike with natbib package. When I change apalike to plainurl it shows me an error.

Comment: @Ingmar thanks for the links. The first two question show how to manually add links to .bib files with href. This is not relevant because I want a single link for journal name and the page range. The third and forth questions are completely irrelevant. The last question is close but asks how to link entire bibliography item to the doi page. This is not quite what I want. None of those questions show how to achieve the result shown in the last screenshot.

Comment: @Evgenii - Just forget what I said, then. I've delete the earlier comments, and will delete this one shortly.

Comment: @Evgenii can you provide the link to the paper you want to imitate? Also, why do you absolutely want to imitate the specific bib style?

Comment: @pluton I've added the list of papers to the end of my question. As I said in the question, I want to add the links so the readers (including myself) can quickly open the paper without a need to search for them. There are many papers that do this and I really liked that as a reader.

Comment: Maybe adding a clickable DOI link (or any other permanent link) is sufficient, in which case many bib styles offer this feature. Otherwise, the arxiv link (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1804.07760v2) gives access to the source files. The authors are using the mnras.bst bib style. You can certainly use it as well.

Comment: @pluton do you mean adding a link with \href to the .bib file? I tried it, but it's not convenient because I need to add it to four places (journal, volume, number, page) and even then, the brackets about "1" (1) in my example are not shown as links. As for the paper source, I downloaded, but I don't see the .bib file there, it's already been compiled into the .bbl, so it does not show me how they did it unfortunately.  Thank for your help, btw.

Comment: Would having a link on the title only (and not name of journal+volume+issue+year) be ok? If yes, you can read https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/419666/371. If not, then it is more challenging :)

Comment: @pluton thank you, this is very relevant, I'll give it a try and hack a bst file to show the links.